# Google maps don't render properly when visibility initially set to hidden

Tags: jquery, google-maps, animation, google-maps-api-3

I have inserted google maps in a animated website, which must make use of the display: hidden property and sliding effects using jquery, but the map does not display properly. You will find that the map is off-center. Please help!!!

**EDIT: The code below has been edited so that it now displays correctly (thanks to Salman) but now it's no longer shows at the centre of the marker. the map.setCenter(myLatlng) did not not work either.**

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.10.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=false"></script>
<script>
    var map //NEW!
    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(52.518903284520796,-1.450427753967233);
    function initialize() {
        var mapOptions = {
            zoom: 13,
            center: myLatlng,
            mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions); //NEW!(SMALL EDIT)

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            position: myLatlng,
            map: map,
            title: 'Beauty Courses 4 U',
            icon: 'http://www.google.com/intl/en_us/mapfiles/ms/micons/pink-dot.png'
        });
    }
    google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
</script>
</head>
<style>
#menu {display: none;}
.sliderContainer {
position: relative;
overflow: hidden;
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
}
.sliderViewer {
position: absolute;
left: 0px;
overflow-x: hidden;
width: 900px;
height: 300px;
}
.sliderViewer>div {
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
float: left;
overflow: hidden;
}
#map_canvas {
width: 200px;
height: 200px;
margin: 0 auto 0 auto;
}
.sliderViewer>div:nth-child(1) {background: red;}
.sliderViewer>div:nth-child(2) {background: yellow;}
.sliderViewer>div:nth-child(3) {background: blue;}
a {cursor: pointer;}
</style>
<body>
<a id="showMenu">Show menu (click here)</a>
<div id="menu">
<ul>
<li id="link1"><a>link1</a></li>
<li id="link2"><a>link2 (click on this link)</a></li>
<li id="link3"><a>link3</a></li>
</ul>
<div class="sliderContainer">
<div class="sliderViewer">
      <div>some conetent in panel 1</div>
      <div>The map is off center:
      <div id="map_canvas"></div></div>
      <div>some conetent in panel 3</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</body>
<script>
$( document ).ready(function(){
    $('#showMenu').on('click', function(){
        $('#menu').show(500);
    })
    $('#link1').on('click',function(){
        $('.sliderViewer').animate({left: 0}, 1000);
        })
    $('#link2').on('click',function(){
        $('.sliderViewer').animate({left: -300}, 1000);
                    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize'); //NEW!
                    map.setCenter(myLatlng); //NEW!
    })
    $('#link3').on('click',function(){
        $('.sliderViewer').animate({left: -600}, 1000);
    })
 });
 </script>
 </html>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to trigger map resize event when you actually display the map.

```
$('#link2').on('click',function(){
    $('.sliderViewer').animate({left: -300}, 1000);
    google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize')
})
```

However this won't work unless you make the `map` variable global. So you can start off like this:

```
var map;
function initialize() {
    // init codes
    map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map_canvas'), mapOptions);
```

Comment: Thats brilliant as the map now displays correctly, but now the map does not centre on the pointer i put (as seen on 'myLatLang' variable)

Comment: if you call `map.setCenter` after resize that should do it.

Comment: Thanks but this still does not work. I have edited the original post to take in account of your changes.

Comment: You didn't pass any parameter to setCenter. You need to pass a LatLng object.

Comment: I've made the myLatlng variable global and change the code to: myMap.setCenter(myLatlng);
however this still does not work. What am i doing wrong????

Comment: I've put it in jsFiddle in here: [Click here for link](http://jsfiddle.net/anik786/NhrF9/)


This is the first time I used jsfiddle. please tell me what i'm doing wrong. (i may have done something wrong using js fiddle as well as the map does not show up at all now on js fiddle site).

Comment: fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/NV8pg/2/, output: http://awesomescreenshot.com/0811ti8m54. Isn't it what you want?

Comment: Thank you so much. just made some silly mistakes when declaring variables.

Answer (score 0):

```
<iframe width="425" height="350" frameborder="0" scrolling="no" marginheight="0" marginwidth="0" 
src="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=chennai&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Chennai,+Tamil+Nadu&amp;ll=13.052414,80.250825&amp;spn=0.991302,1.674042&amp;t=m&amp;z=10&amp;output=embed">
</iframe>
<br/>
<small>
<a href="https://maps.google.co.in/maps?q=chennai&amp;ie=UTF8&amp;hq=&amp;hnear=Chennai,+Tamil+Nadu&amp;ll=13.052414,80.250825&amp;spn=0.991302,1.674042&amp;t=m&amp;z=10&amp;source=embed" style="color:#0000FF;text-align:left">
View Larger Map</a>
</small>
```

u can use this map in html code............

Comment: I don't want to use this as you can't customise the pointer. I may use this as a last resort. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
    google.maps.event.addListenerOnce(map, 'tilesloaded', function() {
            google.maps.event.trigger(map, 'resize');

    });
});
```